# Scale all screen elements with window vb.net wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net

First time working on a GUI project.. and first time doing work on Windows so apologies in advance if this is a really noob question.
I'm taking baby steps into windows programming starting with vb.net WPF. Working in Visual Studio Express 2012.

I'm trying to work out how I can scale all the elements in a window with the window itself.
So for example, I'd create a window, say 1280x720, and place some images in the window. Say one at the top and one in the corner. (this is a basic media based application) 
When I resize that window, I want the entire window to scale with it, so image 1 & 2 will get larger if the window gets larger, however this has to happen proportionally so that if I make the window a lot bigger in one direction one image can't overlap the other. Imagine the window is an image and I'm trying to resize it. (The overlap thing is the closest I've gotten to getting this working in my current attempts).

The layout in produciton will be more complex, comprising of mediaelements (video), images, text etc and all must scale accordingly. 
This isn't something the user interacts with and so there are no form elements etc, and so I don't need form fields etc to stay the same size throughout scaling. I just need everything to scale like I'm scaling a picture. If for example I displayed this 1280x720 (16:9) layout on a 1920x1080 screen, maximised it should look identical only larger.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this.

What I've tried so far- the few articles I did find on google relating to this (I may well be searching the wrong things) lead me to put all the elements in a viewbox, this lead to the overlap I mentioned earlier.

Ideas ?

Comment: Post a screenshoot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to implement it in WPF. Viewbox is the way to go, you should place 2-row grid and a Viewbox in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [ViewBox](http://wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html) container. The basic idea is as follows: `ViewBox` scales its content just as if it was an image scaled. This seems to be the closest result to what you've described in your question. Just put a `Grid` with absolutely-sized columns and rows into the `ViewBox` and set its Stretch to be Uniform:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Grid>
        <..>Your controls, MediaElements, etc
    <Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

You could also combine it (or entirely replace) with (e.g.) [Grid Container](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) : it gives you an ability to specify cell width and size usign star-syntax which is similair to html's percent syntax.

Another way is to use the DockPanel.

All-in-all there are plenty ways to achieve something similair and the way to go largely depends on the nuances of your particulair requirements. 
Have a look at [This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans#heading0005) to see a good overview of WPF containers and how to use them.